# asp mvc, best solution to store user input data before it will be saved to database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, caching

for example i've got a form with some input fields(every form and it's inputs with validation rules are stored in database).
Every input got it's own OnChange() which posts json (i.e. new value, input element name, ...) to controller for validation, if validation passes the new value must be saved somewhere until user clicks submit button, which will save all data to database table.

And here i'd like to ask, what this special place between ui and database can be ?

p.s.
also if user closes browser/form the next time he'll come back i need to ask him if he would like to start from an empty form or fill form with values he previously entered there.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies or intermediary database table would work for this case.

Comment: hi. thx for reply. is it ok to have one table where all user form input will be stored in xml format ? and every time user update form field i just update corresponding xml ?

Comment: It is absolutely normal. Just be careful with the big number of users working simultaneously. I would recommend having the usual structure of table, which contains columns corresponding to the fields on your form, - such a table will be easier to work with, as you will not need to manipulate xml every time user updates the form field.

Comment: but with usual table structure it will be necessary to create intermediary table for every main table )

Comment: so you have more than one table? then, maybe you could create a table with structure like this: TempTable { MainTableID, Field, Value }. Anyway, this is not a mandatory and you could go with xml field, though this can become a problem in the future. That's the reason for my alternatives to xml approach for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

for an intermediary database like that, you could use something like MongoDB, it is really easy to get it started, you just work with the classes you have, don't need to setup any schema, you just save the objects

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the entire form at the end, why can't you just store the values at that time? Is this a multi-page form(s)? Why not allow the database records to be partially filled? You could always add a bit column to mark the record as complete or incomplete. This would be much simpler than duplicating your table structure.